# Cannot view Site contents

Tags: modern-experience, site-contents

This is definitely a bug but I wanted to report it here to see if anyone else has experienced this or heard from Microsoft. Is there a workaround for this where I can actually view Site Contents?

From any site collection, if I click Site contents, it redirects to the Modern page that is completely blank!

```
/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14
```

[image]

The suite bar is gone, the Hub site navigation is gone, there is no settings cog wheel or contents. When I switch to the 'Subsites' tab, the Office Menu now appears

```
/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=15
```

[image]

I can't view my site contents in any site (not just those associated with Hub sites). WTF Microsoft, I took 6 months off from SharePoint and come back to an Online environment riddled with silly bugs like this *disappointed

Comment: sorry to say we have never experienced this as working continuously to Modern online environment from Jan 2017. and Yes changes keep coming and it might affected to you now.Sometimes if we drop our Internet Connection this happens.I saw many times Suit bar is not appearing and i saw my Proxy Internet is disabled thats why it was not appearing.

Comment: thanks for response. It is super weird I'm waiting on a regular user account (not global admin) to test with

Comment: This just happened to me too - @Colbs - were you able to resolve?

Comment: @matt I submitted a ticket with MS and it magically resolved itself the next day.